# The execution of the program doesn't end though the program executed successfully when using threads

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

I am exploring `java.util.concurrent.*`
Calculating the square and waiting using `Thread.sleep(5000)` , the program works as expected, but never terminates.

The red square in eclipse is "ON", that we usually use to terminate the program.

Can you please help in understanding why the program doesn't terminate on completion??

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
        SquareCalculator sqC = new SquareCalculator();
        sqC.display(1);
        Future<Integer> result = sqC.calculate(5);

        while(!result.isDone())
        {
            System.out.println("Waiting for the calculation");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            //result.cancel(true);
        }
        Integer square = result.get();
        System.out.println(square);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Calclulation was interrupted");
        }
    }
```

```
public class SquareCalculator {

    private ExecutorService ex = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    public void display(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    public Future<Integer> calculate(Integer inp)
    {
        try {
            System.out.println("Before sending request");
        Future<Integer> res = ex.submit(()->{

            Thread.sleep(5000);
            return inp*inp;
        });
        System.out.println("Request sent to caluclate and waiting for the result");
        return res;
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("calculation was interrupted");
            return null;
        }
        //return ex.submit(()->squareing(inp));

    }

}
```

OUTPUT

```
1
Before sending request
Request sent to caluclate and waiting for the result
Waiting for the calculation
Waiting for the calculation
Waiting for the calculation
Waiting for the calculation
Waiting for the calculation
25
```

Comment: Please edit your question with one thing in mind: it should be a question! What are you asking?

Comment: You need to call `ExecutorService.shutdown()` on your single thread executor to ensure that the Thread shuts down - if non-daemon threads are running, the VM doesn't exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refactor your code and return the object instead of Future. You should also shutdown executor when you are done.

```java
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class SquareCalculator {

    private ExecutorService ex = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    public void display(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    public Integer calculate(Integer inp) {
        Integer result;
        try {
            System.out.println("Before sending request");
            Future<Integer> res = ex.submit(() -> {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                return inp * inp;
            });
            System.out.println("Request sent to caluclate and waiting for the result");
            result = res.get();
            ex.shutdown();
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("calculation was interrupted");
            return null;
        }
        //return ex.submit(()->squareing(inp));

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, 
        ExecutionException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            SquareCalculator sqC = new SquareCalculator();
            sqC.display(1);
            Integer result = sqC.calculate(5);
            System.out.println(result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Calclulation was interrupted");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I added some getters to get the executor and shut-it down.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather create an executor outside the Calculator class and the pass it in the constructor.

This way the application has control over the `ExecutorService` and shut it down when necessary.

Also, if you create more then one instance of a calculator, all instance use the same executor service, so you can control how many instance can run in parallel.

Blocking in the calculate method works, but defeats the purpose of using another thread to make an async calculation.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // The executor is created by the application and then 
        // passed to the calculator
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        SquareCalculator calculator = new SquareCalculator(executor);

        // calculate does not block
        Future<Integer> calculate = calculator.calculate(12);

        try {
            while(true) {
                try {
                    // wait a limited amount of time for the computation to complete   
                    Integer result = calculate.get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    System.out.println(result);
                    if(calculate.isDone()) {
                        // If the computation was either complete or cancelled just quit 
                        break;
                    }
                } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                    // We expect timeouts so we don't quit the loop for them
                    System.out.println("Waiting for result");
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            // If there was an error or the computation was interrupted just quit.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Shut down the executor so we do not leak pools. 
        executor.shutdown();
    }
```

```
    public class SquareCalculator {

        private ExecutorService ex;

        public SquareCalculator(ExecutorService ex) {
            super();
            this.ex = ex;
        }

        public void display(int i) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }

        public Future<Integer> calculate(Integer inp) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Before sending request");
                Future<Integer> res = ex.submit(() -> {

                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    return inp * inp;
                });
                System.out.println("Request sent to caluclate and waiting for the result");
                return res;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("calculation was interrupted");
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want the VM to shut down, call `System.exit()`. Yes, the VM can automatically close without calling that method as well; it does this if ALL still 'live' threads have the 'daemon' flag up (the Thread class has a .setDaemon method for this purpose), but that's bad code style. If the point is to shut down, then shut down (with `System.exit`).

Specifically here, the threads created by Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(); aren't marked as daemon threads. You can fix that by supplying a thread creator to the call.

But, really, don't. Use `System.exit`.

Comment: What you say is correct but I would use `System.exit()` with extreme care. I think I could use it in a `main` but not elsewhere, because it could lead to unexpected results. Imagine the same problem applied to an application server where you start a thread to make some computation. Tearing down the entire VM could be too much.

Comment: In such a case OP wouldn't have any problem; the server isn't supposed to shut down and it doesn't. If you call System.exit(), the VM exits. If you want that, great. IF you don't, then don't call it. What's there to be 'extremely careful' about?